# navigation tabs in android with ABS nullpointerexception when inflating menu

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I have a problem. This code works fine on my nexus 10 android 4.2.1. But on AVD android 2.3 it gives me

```
NullPointerException com.example.training.ContentFragment.onCreateOptionsMenu(ContentFragment.java:97)
```

So I have two navigation tabs with two fragments each for one tabs.

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    activity.getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.trainings_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)

this method has already brought MenuInflater refference, you don't need to call it, simply use provided one

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Menu and MenuInflater in public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) should be from Sherlock package.
com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu and com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    //first call the parent to default behavior
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);        
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    activity.getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.trainings_menu, menu);
}
```

The menu inflater is already passed as param to the method.

Hope it helps.